# Is it possible to have separated logs for each postgresql schema in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pm2

I'm using nodejs with postgres database and a lot of schemas (and pm2 as process manager).
Each schema is a user, so in every query i pass schema name as parameter.
At the moment all console.logs are written on a single file, rotated by pm2.
 My goal is to have a separated log for every schema/user, for example user_1.log, user_2.log and so on.
Is there a way/node module to make this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about passing custom log file path and environment variable when starting pm2 process?

```
SCHEMA_USER=user_1 pm2 start app.js -i 1 -o ./logs/user_1.log -e ./logs/user_1.err

SCHEMA_USER=user_2 pm2 start app.js -i 1 -o ./logs/user_2.log -e ./logs/user_2.err
```

or You can use [simple-node-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-logger) and make logger storage which will deliver objects that will log to Your desired location.

create `log-manager.js` somewhere with such content:

```
const path = require('path');
const SimpleNodeLogger = require('simple-node-logger'),

class LogManager {
  static instances = {};

  static get(key) {
    if (!key) return console;
    if (Logger.instances[key]) return Logger.instances[key];

    const opts = {
        logFilePath: path.join(__dirname, 'logs', key+'.log'),
        timestampFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'
    },
    return Logger.instances[key] = SimpleNodeLogger.createSimpleLogger(opts);
  }
}

module.exports = LogManager;
```

and use it for example with express application:

```
const logManager = require('./log-manager');

request.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const logger = logManager.get('user_' + req.params.id);
  // doing somethings
  logger.error('User not found');
  req.status(404).send({});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i start only 1 process for all schemas, i don't think your solution is possibile. I'm thinking about a log system inside node instead the default one of pm2.

Comment: @massimomaioli then You have to spawn per process per schema user from main process. Or You've to write Your own console logger library that will be abstraction on console.log and will dynamically switch between log destinations.

Comment: @massimomaioli I've updated my answer with log manager example